# How to configure Magento 2 Layered Navigation Attributes?

Tags: magento2

I want to *Configure magento 2 Layered Navigation Attributes* in the time saving way. Can you show me what I can do?

Answer (score -1):

It is very easy for you.You can follow this tutorial in Magento 2:
http://www.venustheme.com/magento-2-layered-navigation-with-filterable-attributes/

*Step 1*: Create attributes properties:

Log in *Magento Admin Panel –> Stores –> Attributes / Product*

In each attribute, choose attributes and edit it
Then select *“Storefront Properties”*

*Step 2:* Make the Category *"Anchor"*

*Products –> Categories*
Choose the category which you need to apply layered navigation.

Tap the Display Settings tab:

- Is Anchor field: Choose “YES”
  And then “SAVE” Category to complete.

*Step 3*: Test layered Navigation for filterable attributes

After you “SAVE”.  You return to go the store. Then click to section you want to filterable Layered Navigation attributes. Just like it.

If you have any hesitations to our tutorials, please view more at our Magento 2 Tutorials to deepen your knowledge in Magento 2.

Answer (score -1):

I think that if we are talking about configuration the best plugin is [Layered Navigation](http://ecommerce.aheadworks.com/magento-2-extensions/layered-navigation) for Magento 2 by Aheadworks. I began to apply this extension not so much time ago. But I feel it is a right choice.
Do you know that complicated navigation is among top three reasons why customers leave store without shopping? And once having had a bad shopping experience this client never visits the store again. To avoid such sad cases Aheadworks has created Layered Navigation for Magento 2 remembering that shopping must be comfortable primarily. How is it provided?
The customers often don’t know how is the final set of products will look like. So it is good solution to implement attributes multi selection. It reduces time that can be spent on step by step selection considerably allowing customers to compare and make better choice.
Coming back to what may be called the advantages of this extension I would like to point out the following benefit. The users may find here such a pleasant option is possibility to add new relevant filters like New arrivals’, ‘Discounted products’, ‘In-stock Items’, and ‘Price Slider’. All these filters compose multi-attribute list that the developer has made compact. 
These are just my personal remarks about this good plugin. I advise to apply it in case of having problems related to complicated navigation.